# I am practicing RegEx in PHP. Why doesn't this simple regExp work?

Tags: php, regex

I am practicing RegEx in PHP. I know it is not that good to use it for HTML string manipulation but there are times when DOMDocument is not available in the PHP environment I work with.

```
$a ='bsrc="lalala"';

$t = preg_replace('/(src="([^"]*)")/i', '\2', $a);
```

So I am trying to get `lalala` from the string but for some reasons it doesn't work. I got `blalalaa` in return;

I tried escaping the `"` and write `'/(src=\"([^\"]*)\")/i'` but to no avail. I am doing it in a `preg_replace_callback` function, can that be the reason?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it supposed to say `bscr=` in your `$a`? (You are matching `<src`)

Comment: @TiiJ7 sorry I was careless. it was supposed to be just `src="`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get a match then you need to use `preg_match` instead of `preg_replace`:

```
$a ='<src="lalala"a';
if (preg_match('/<src="([^"]*)"/i', $a, $m))
    print_r($m[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks! The syntax works now. But in the actual codes it is still not working (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159738/why-doesnt-preg-match-work-in-a-function-of-preg-replace-callback). I suspect it has to do with `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 1):

You should change your regular expression as

```
src=\"([^\"]*)\"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Uq6n9dWdrag70NIA)

Final PHP must be

```
$t = preg_replace('~src=\"([^\"]*)\"~i', '\2', $a);
```

Comment: May I know what does `~` do?

Comment: It's just a delimiter http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: It means like the / character. I prefer to use the tilde instead of the slash because sometimes I write regular expression that must match the slash character. http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: If you want to match instead of replacement see the answer of @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are searching for `<src` and the string does not have this. Your test string should be `<src="lalala"` and not `bsrc..`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $a ='bsrc="lalala"a';

    if (preg_match('/src="(.*)"/i', $a, $matches))
    {
            if (isset($matches[1]))
            {
                 echo "Found value: " .$matches[1]. "\n";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "Not found\n";
            }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not found\n";
    }
```