# Why doesn't preg_match work in a function of preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, html, regex

I know it is not that good to use it for HTML string manipulation but there are times when DOMDocument is not available in the PHP environment I work with.

```
preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {

    $z = $matches[2];
    preg_match('/src="([^"]*)"/i', $z, $t);

    //a lot of string manipulation going on here

    return $t[0].'and'.$matches[2];

}, $content_taken_FROM_HTML);
```

The `$matches[1]` here is `'src="a.jpg"'`;

If I put  `$z='src="a.jpg"'`, it works. But as long as I leave it as `$z= $matches[1];`, which should give the same string, it doesn't work.

What is going on here? And how can this be solved?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at your return statement.

Comment: Do you need `$z = $matches[2];` or `$z = $matches[1];`

Comment: @MMM yup! you are very observant!

Comment: Can you show output of `var_dump($matches);`

Comment: @anubhava the `"` of the original string is escaped by `\\`

Comment: You can edit your question and provide the output of `var_dump($matches);`

Comment: @anubhava Aha! Thanks! Problem solved! Thanks for suggesting `var_dump`

Answer (score 1):

The `"` in the original string is escaped by `\`, probably caused by a built-in in `preg_replace_callback()` for `$matches`.

Should have `stripslashes()`, my friends!

> stripslashes()
>
> Un-quotes a quoted string.

Thanks anubhava for suggesting `var_dump($matches)`. A good way to debug indeed!